# How can I tell which router a device is connected to?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have four Asus routers (main one RT-AC68U, two RT-AC57U's and an old RT-N66U) ethernetted together to provide four separate WiFi access points around our house/garden.  They're all on the same SSID/password.  Most things work pretty good in most places, but there's a couple of problem spots/devices.

How can I tell which router a (say) WiFi IP camera is currently attached to?  The device list in the routers web interface doesn't seem to be very useful - sometimes none of them will show a device at all, othertimes all 4 of them will list the device.  I semi-understand why this is, but given that those lists don't help, what tool can I utilise?

Each router is on a different channel, if that helps.

Comment: If it were a device with an interface (e.g. a windows laptop) you could look at the [BSSID](https://www.speedcheck.org/wiki/bssid/#:~:text=Basic%20service%20set%20identifiers%20(BSSID)%20is%20used%20to%20describe%20sections,conforms%20to%20MAC%2D48%20conventions.) the device connects to and lookup the BSSID's of your routers to understand what router is providing the connection.
Does your WiFi IP camera have some interface showing information about the connection?

Comment: From a command prompt: `netsh wlan show networks bssid` would show you the channel on a Windows computer.